# можно ли функцию запихнуть в условие if

Tags: python, tkinter

Я делаю проверку на содержание текста и сохранён ли он перед тем как закрыть главное окно `Tk()`. Я хочу что бы проверяла выполнилась так: `if  save() or save_as() != True:` если ли хотя бы одна из функций вызывалась, то дальше указаный код

```
    if messagebox.askokcancel('Quit','Are you sure you want to quitwithout being saved ?'):
        root.destroy()
else:
    if messagebox.askokcancel('Quit','Are you sure you want to quit?'):
        root.destroy()`
```

, но мне код сразу вызывает эти функции `save()`  `save_as():`

Вот исходник

```
def save():
    global f

    a=text.get('1.0',END+'-1c')
    if f == '':
        f=filedialog.asksaveasfile(filetypes = (("new files","*.pain"),("all files","*.*")),
                                defaultextension='.pain')
    if f != None:
        file = open(f.name,'w')
        file.write(a)
        file.close()


def save_as():
    f=filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w',filetypes = (("new files","*.pain"),("all files","*.*")),
                            defaultextension='.pain')


    if f != None:
        a=text.get('1.0',END+'-1c')
    t=text.get(0.0,END)
    try:
        f.write(t.rstrip())
    except:
        messagebox.showerror('Fault!','Fail not saved')
```

Comment: или как по-другом осуществить проверку

Comment: Добавь в конец функций "return True". Когда функция выполнилась правильно она вернет "True" иначе будет возвращать "None" (по умолчанию)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте переменную `is_saved`, которая изначально будет равна `False`, а в функциях `save` и `save_as` присваивайте ей `True`.

```
if  is_saved != True:
    if messagebox.askokcancel('Quit','Are you sure you want to quitwithout being saved ?'):
        root.destroy()
else:
    if messagebox.askokcancel('Quit','Are you sure you want to quit?'):
        root.destroy()`
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение без всяких переменных

```
def save():
    global f

    a=text.get('1.0',END+'-1c')
    if f == '':
        f=filedialog.asksaveasfile(filetypes = (("new files","*.pain"),("all files","*.*")),
                                defaultextension='.pain')
    if f != None:
        file = open(f.name,'w')
        file.write(a)
        file.close()
        return True
    else:
        return False

def save_as():
    f=filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w',filetypes = (("new files","*.pain"),("all files","*.*")),
                            defaultextension='.pain')


    if f != None:
        a=text.get('1.0',END+'-1c')
    t=text.get(0.0,END)
    try:
        f.write(t.rstrip())
        return True
    except:
        messagebox.showerror('Fault!','Fail not saved')
        return False

if  save() != True or save_as() != True:
    if messagebox.askokcancel('Quit','Are you sure you want to quitwithout being saved ?'):
        root.destroy()
else:
    if messagebox.askokcancel('Quit','Are you sure you want to quit?'):
        root.destroy()
```